# rails how to declare a variable and store a value in html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hi i have a value like this in html.erb

```
<img src="<%= file.title, file_path(file) %>" alt=""/>
```

but when I placed the above code it throws an error

```
 SyntaxError in Files#index
```

the error comes on `file_path(file)` section . Is there  a way to accomplish this ? like declare a variable and assign it to something ?

Comment: That I know :) Thank you

Comment: I don't think `file_path()` does what you thought it would do see this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Generators/NamedBase.html#method-i-file_path unless you have your own helper function with that name…

What exactly is your `file`?

Comment: your error says that you have a wrong syntax. if you look at your code, `<%= file.title, file_path(file) %>` doesn't really make sense. either you want a link wherein you need to use `link_to` or you want to just use `file_path(file)` assuming that it returns a valid url for the image that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I did not get whay you are trying to achieve but you can try to do it like this

```
<img src="<%= "#{file.title}, #{file_path(file)}" %>" alt=""/>
```

Comment: well ya thats what um trying to do but its not work here . Thank you

Comment: Can you post your action? and routes?

Comment: this prevents the syntax error but it doesn't make sense that this is the answer.  acts_as_geek's answer makes better sense

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `file` (a better naming is `@file`) in the controller action which is associated with this view. There you can do whatever you want with your variable.

Comment: cant we declare  a variable in html.erb like in  Jinja templates?

Comment: you can just use: <% file = "whatever you like" %>, but why would you do it?